# Fetching from Redux-Toolkit store returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I'm refactoring my code from "old" Redux to Redux-toolkit, but now my code won't retrieve data from the store,
i double checked if i made mistake many times.
this is the code:

```
reduxStore

import {
  Action,
  configureStore,
  EnhancedStore,
  ThunkAction,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import tablesReducer from "./slices/tablesSlice";
// import bookingsReducer from "./slices/bookingsReducer";

import { DefaultStateI, TableI } from "../Interfaces";

export const configureStoreWithMiddlewares = (): EnhancedStore => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      tables: tablesReducer,
      // bookings: bookingsReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }),

    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  });
  return store;
};

export const store = configureStoreWithMiddlewares();

// // Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
// // Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
// // export default store;

export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
```

this is the Slice:

```
tablesSlice

import {
    createAction,
    createAsyncThunk,
    createReducer,
    createSlice,
    PayloadAction,
  } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
  import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";
  import { stat } from "fs";
  import { TableI } from "../../Interfaces";
  import { RootState } from "../reduxStore";
  
  export enum RetrieveState {
    Loading,
    Loaded,
    Error,
  }
  
  type RetrieveTables = {
    tables: TableI[];
  };

  
  
  export const fetchAllTables = createAsyncThunk(
    "tables/fetchAllTables",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get<RetrieveTables>(
        "http://localhost:5000/tables"
        );
        return response.data.tables;
      } catch (error) {
        const axiosError = error as AxiosError;
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ errorMessage: axiosError.message });
    }
  }
);

const tablesSlice: any = createSlice({
  name: "tables",
  initialState: {
    tables: new Array<TableI>(),
    tablesFiltered: [],
    capacity: 0,
    location: "",
    bookings: [],
    error: RetrieveState.Error,
    loading: false,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchAllTables.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchAllTables.fulfilled, (state: any, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.tables = action.payload as TableI[];
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchAllTables.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload as RetrieveState.Error;
    });
  },
});

export const tablesSelector = (state: RootState) => {
  return state.tables.tables;
};

export default tablesSlice.reducer;
```

then i simply fetch the data in

```
App.tsx

// React
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

// Redux
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchAllTables } from "./store/slices/tablesSlice";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();**

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAllTables());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const tables: Array<TableI> = useSelector(tablesSelector);
  console.log(tables)
```

if i `console.log(tables)` the result is `'undefined'`,
i'm really struggling to understand why it's not working
i also double-checked the endpoint and that url works fine

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found the solution, it was a very simple mistake.
in `tablesSlice` was trying this:

return response.data.tables;

i just needed to do:

```
return response.data;
```

now it finally works!